# AvisynthplusのLinuxでのビルド方法を教えてください。

Tags: linux, avisynth-plus

Wineを使って、Windows版をインストールしましたがうまくいきませんので、
[ここ](https://github.com/AviSynth/AviSynthPlus/releases)からソースコードをダウンロードして、以下を実施しました。

```
% cmake .
% make
```

しかし、以下のようなエラーがでてしまい、解決方法が見つかりません。
対策を教えていただけないでしょうか？

```
make[2]:  [avs_core/CMakeFiles/AvsCore.dir/convert/convert_yv12.cpp.o] エラー 1 
make[1]:  [avs_core/CMakeFiles/AvsCore.dir/all] エラー 2
```

[環境]
OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit

Comment: 今のところAvisynth+はLinuxに対応していないようです。

Comment: 同じ様にソースコードの make を行ってみましたが、こちらの環境では windows.h が無いため最初のファイルのコンパイルで失敗してしまいした。

Comment: heliac2001さん。実験ありがとうございます。
もし、対処方法が見つかりましたら教えていただけると助かります。